# XAMPP 1.7.4 Error: myst be run on root directory

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

My latest XAMPP was working fine but uninstalled it because the codes that were made my classmate wont run on mine and she can only run it with older XAMPP. But it wont run. I tried 1.7.5 it still doesnt work.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is the command that gives you the title error? What's the error obtained using the latest Xampp version?

Comment: @Cynical when im in the xampp control panel, when i start apache and mysql, it stops immediately.

Comment: Have you checked the apache and mysql log files for clues? Normally they are inside the Xampp directory, or `/var/log/` under *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

PHP.INI add:

extension=php_openssl.dll

extension=php_intl.dll

Comment: where is that? In php.ini-development or prduction?

Comment: apache and mysql starts and stops immediately.